# How to decrypt p7s files

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I need to upload some files on my server.To problem is that the files are encrypted(.p7s extension) and i want to decrypt them first.

[This is the application i'm using to remove the encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBllD.png)

There is anyway to remove the encryption directly from my java code?I read something about bouncycastle library, but i really don't know how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: p7s conventionally means signed data (not encrypted) but you appear to have used it for a pkcs7 containing certificate or cert chain, which are conventionally designated p7b or p7c (also not encrypted). If it is in fact a pkcs7 cert/chain (p7b) `generateCertificates()` _or_ `generateCertPath` in [`java.security.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) (from either SUN or BC provider) can read and parse it. BC _also_ has several 'lightweight' options.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Application called Keytool to read those files. The app is distributed with every java sdk. The code is implemented in Java, so you should be able to debug the application.

No need for bountycastle, even if the documentation is better.

Comment: `keytool` can read p7b format (assuming that's what OP has) only when it matches and updates a privatekey entry already in the keystore. For other cases it can only read a single, 'bare' cert.